# Filter objects inside model class by date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model object called `EventListingResponse` like this

```
public class EventListingResponse
{
    public List<events> result { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
}
 public class events
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; } //smaple date 2014-03-31T12:30:03
}
```

And I am storing data in this object like this

```
EventListingResponse eventListResponse = rGetAllEventList();//data from another function.
```

Now I want to filter this list so that I can get a list of `events` like , 
-->events from January
-->Events from February etc.
Can any one point out a good method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define string array of months u wanted to be filtered with

```
string[] monthresult = { "January", "March" };
```

using Linq

```
 var filteredresults = eventListResponse.result.Where(o => monthresult.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(o.startDate).ToString("MMMM")));
```

filteredresults will content list of events with month January and March

Comment: I am not sure whether you looked in to sample data i provided or not,
smaple date 2014-03-31T12:30:03

Comment: If you considered it, Then please tell me how i could fetch data from filteredresults  too

Comment: it works but u can still use Parse instead of convert

Edit: u can retrieve values like this:
            foreach (events i in filteredresults)
            {
                i.id
                i.name
                i.startDate
            }

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LINQ query to filter your list:

```
var filtered = from item in eventListResponse.result
               where DateTime.Parse(item.startDate) >= DateTime.Parse("your starting date")
               and DateTime.Parse(item.startDate) <= DateTime.Parse("your ending date")
               select item;
```

You also need to change your assignment of the data from `rGetAllEventList()` to go into `eventListResponse.result`.

Comment: There is a little issue with your code, I can't give start date and end date to filter. I just want it to filter out each month data. May be I can give 12 month names as input thats it.

Comment: You would need to replace the *your starting date* with *2014-01-01* and *your ending date* with *2014-01-31* to get January.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
            EventListingResponse evl = new EventListingResponse();
        evl.result = new List<events>();
        evl.result.Add(new events() { id = "1", name = "test1", startDate = "2014-03-31T12:30:03" });
        evl.result.Add(new events() { id = "2", name = "test2", startDate = "2014-03-31T14:30:03" });
        evl.result.Add(new events() { id = "3", name = "test3", startDate = "2014-05-31T16:30:03" });
        evl.result.Add(new events() { id = "4", name = "test4", startDate = "2014-05-31T12:30:03" });

        var dated_EventListResponse = evl.result.Select(t => new { date = DateTime.Parse(t.startDate), MyEvent = t });

        var grouped_EventListResponse = dated_EventListResponse.GroupBy(g => g.date.Month);

        foreach (var group in grouped_EventListResponse)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Filter: " + group.Key);
            foreach (var grouped_event in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + grouped_event.MyEvent.name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a software system and I can't hard code dates as you told in the question. that will break the entire system one day.

Comment: the first 6 lines are just example data... try to understand the code before downvoting.